# Permission denied while cloning project in htdocs

Tags: linux, git, xampp, gitlab

I am new to linux and I am trying to clone a project into a folder that am currently in contained in `opt/lampp/htdocs` using the command `git clone git@gitlab.com:whatever .` but i am getting a permission denied error. What can i do to resolve this issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to **give full permission** to your htdocs folder

> sudo chmod 777  opt/lampp/htdocs

Then it will ask for password enter and go ahead. [learn More Here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm) :)

Answer (score 0):

update httpd.conf

```
 sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

Find

```
 User nobody
 Group nogroup
```

Replace **nobody** with your **username**

Change the ownership of htdocs

```
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Change the file permissions of htdocs folder

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Restart your machine

Clear your browser cache

Answer (score 0):

You can also give the folder full permissions like this:
`sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/`
or `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/lampp/htdocs`

Answer (score 0):

I already have my username correctly wrote in user in the `httpd.conf` file, and still had the same problem. Finally, I found the solution changing the port number:

- In the same file look for `Local:8888` and change `8888` to `80`

Answer (score -1):

Permission denied is exactly what it says. You do not have permission to write to this folder. You can either git clone the repo as a root using `sudo git clone (...)` or change permissions to this folder. `sudo chmod a+w <path>` and then `git clone` it normally. You can also clone the repository to some other folder to which you already have permissions to write to.